# Output message problems with procedure and function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, procedure

I have successfully created a function and a trigger but the output does not seem to be showing when i execute it just says procedure completed successfully. It does not display the total cost.

Comment: Where do you run your procedure? Did you `set serveroutput on`?

Answer (score 4):

To see the output from the DBMS_OUTPUT package, you must enable it. That depends on the tool you are using.

- in SQL+, set the command `set serveroutput on` before running the procedure
- in TOAD, click on the Output On/Off button in the DBMS_OUTPUT tab
- in SQL Developer you also have a tab named DBMS_OUTPUT, click on the the first icon to enable the output